# SQLException: Illegal connection port value ${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, openshift

I am trying to deploy a fairly basic Spring+Hibernate web app to my newly created app. (I am new to openshift).

I have followed [this](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/kb/kb-e1076-default-database-connectivity-configurations-for-jboss-applications) example from the knowledge base.

But after deploying the application i am getting

```
..
java.sql.SQLException: Illegal connection port value '${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}'
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2018)
..
```

I have defined the datasource in my applicationcontext.xml

This is the section in my applicationContext.xml that I define the deta shource (eli is the database name)

```
<bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="jdbc:mysql://${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/eli" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error you're receiving seems to indicate that the property replacement strings in your Spring XML configuration aren't actually being processed by Spring. You can add a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to your configuration to enable processing from the system environment:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
  ...
</bean>
```